# How to get a tuple with each parameter instead of the final result using itertools?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to combine the elements of three lists with each other. I want to combine each element with each element in a specific way:

element * element ** element

I want the values ​​of each parameter. The condition is that a certain total value is not exceeded.

Actually I used itertools and product. I was able to recieve the highest total value but not the value of each parameter. And i don´t know how to integrate the condition.

```py
from itertools import product

List1 = list(range(1,4))
List2 = list(range(4,8))
List3 = list(range(3,7))

result = ([m*(n**o) for m,n,o in product(List1,List2,List3)])
max(result)
```

The output is actually 352947, but i expect something like [4,8,7]. In a next step I would like to add a condition. I want the value for each parameter, but the total should not exceed 15000. Can you guys help me out, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include `m`, `n` and `o` inside a tuple along with the calculated value `m*(n**o)` as each element in the list comprehension. Then use a lambda to get the max of your resulting list using the calculated value as the key:

```
from itertools import product

List1 = list(range(1,4))
List2 = list(range(4,8))
List3 = list(range(3,7))

result = ([(m, n, o, m*(n**o)) for m,n,o in product(List1,List2,List3)])
max_m, max_n, max_o, max_value = max(result, key=lambda tup: tup[3])
```

Comment: Thank you, but i dont get the point how to add a condition. Your code gives me the following output: 3 7 6 352947. How can i set a maximum value like 150000 for example?

Comment: You can add the condition to the list comprehension itself: `result = ([(m, n, o, m*(n**o)) for m,n,o in product(List1,List2,List3) if m*(n**o) <= 150000])`